# AutoIt GUICtrlRead

Tags: autoit

I am trying to find a place for

```
$Password = GUICtrlRead($PasswordInput)
```

inside of

```
Func BeginningGUI()
   #Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
   $Form1 = GUICreate("Stronghold Kingdoms", 248, 95, -1, -1)
   $PasswordInput = GUICtrlCreateInput("Password", 8, 32, 233, 21, BitOR($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_INPUT,$ES_PASSWORD))
   $ButtonOk = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 86, 64, 75, 25, $BS_NOTIFY)
   $ButtonCancel = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 167, 64, 75, 25, $BS_NOTIFY)
   $EnterPassLabel = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please Enter Your Stronghold Kingdoms Password", 0, 12, 241, 17, 0)
   GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
   #EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

   While 1
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
  Switch $nMsg
     Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
     Case $ButtonCancel
        Exit
     Case $ButtonOk
        OpenSHK()
        Exit
  EndSwitch
   WEnd
EndFunc

Func OpenSHK()
   Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefly Studios\Stronghold Kingdoms\StrongholdKingdoms.exe")
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms")
   Sleep(5000)
   Send($Password)
   MouseClick("left",927,163)
   Sleep(5000)
   MouseClick("left",1112,371)
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms - World 8")
   sleep(10000)
EndFunc
```

I just need to declare what they enter as $Password for later use.

I tried putting it below Case $ButtonOk but it gave an error about the variable not being declared.

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work?

Comment: Later in the program I tried to Send($Password) but it said that the variable was not defined. I had tried it right above OpenSHK() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it after the $ButtonOK is clicked, before calling `OpenSHK()`:

```
Func BeginningGUI()
  GLOBAL $Password
  ...
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
  Switch $nMsg
     Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
     Case $ButtonCancel
        Exit
     Case $ButtonOk
        $Password = GUICtrlRead($PasswordInput)            
        OpenSHK()
        Exit
  EndSwitch
   WEnd
EndFunc
```

You need to have declared the `$Password` variable first (as I did with the `GLOBAL` at the start of the function code), or modify your `OpenSHK()` function to accept it as a parameter, as in `OpenSHK($Password)`. In the second case, you can simply add `LOCAL $Passenger` at the beginning of your `BeginningGUI` function instead of `GLOBAL`.

```
Func BeginningGUI()
  LOCAL $Password
  ...
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
  Switch $nMsg
     Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
     Case $ButtonCancel
        Exit
     Case $ButtonOk
        $Password = GUICtrlRead($PasswordInput)            
        OpenSHK($Password)
        Exit
  EndSwitch
   WEnd
EndFunc

Func OpenSHK($Password)
   Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefly Studios\Stronghold Kingdoms\StrongholdKingdoms.exe")
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms")
   Sleep(5000)
   Send($Password)
   MouseClick("left",927,163)
   Sleep(5000)
   MouseClick("left",1112,371)
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms - World 8")
   sleep(10000)
EndFunc
```

Comment: Please actually read the words that are written. :-) I said you have to **modify your OpenSHK function to accept a parameter**. Give me a second...